# Facebook Javascript API authorization in UIWebView on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got a page on my site where I'm using the Facebook Javascript API to authorize a Facebook user and get their accessToken. This page works fine when I use iOS Safari.. it opens a new "tab", I login and then the new "tab" automatically gets closed.

But when I try to do it in a UIWebView, it loads the Facebook login screen and once I've logged in it just displays a blank white page. It doesn't redirect back to my oauth url or anything like that.

Is there a way to force the JS api to redirect to my oauth url after oauth is complete?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Nope, I just had to use Safari. :(